# How do people know a person is a knight in westeros?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In **A Song of Ice and Fire** universe, how do people know that a man is a knight? Is there any symbol or proof by which people know someone for a knight? Is there any written proof to prove a person's knighthood?

Comment: Knighthood is usually bestowed in a ceremony with witnesses. Those witnesses are called upon to verify someone's status as a Knight, should the question ever arise. See the case of Ser Duncan at Ashford and Ser Glendon Flowers at Whitewalls.

Comment: Knight's wear armour obviously.

Comment: @Servitor, but not everyone in armor is a knight... ;)

Comment: [Another mandatory reference](https://youtu.be/QIflxDqX7Tg).  The key part starts at 0:15